# Jquery alert output issue

Tags: jquery

This short piece of code displays the date of the first day of the current week. The format displayed in the alert box is a very long format. How do I format the date to get something like "12-1-2012".I broke my head trying to test things I read on other posts. Oh, and I would like to format the date but keep it as a date. No string. Nothing works. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

```
var now = new Date();
var weekDay=new Date().getDay();
now.setDate(now.getDate()-(weekDay-1));
alert(now);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
var now = new Date();
var weekDay=new Date().getDay();
now.setDate(now.getDate()-(weekDay-1));
alert((now.getMonth()+1) + "-" + now.getDate() + "-" + now.getFullYear());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wJQBe/

You can also take a look at this date formatter JavaScript library http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Hello Shankar. Thank you for your help. it work's. But now this output is becoming a string right? If I put that output in a variable and use it to cross with date fields from my remote database will it work?

Comment: You can take it in a variable and use it to compare with remote datebase date provided you convert that date also in the same format.

Comment: Is it not possible to format and keep it as a date format? It is actually what I am looking for.

Comment: You have to serialize it in order to send it to server. You cannot send the JavaScript `Date` object as it is.

Comment: So you confirm that there is no way to format the date and keep it as a date despite using external plugins (else than jquery and jquery-ui)?

Comment: My answer is purely JavaScript way to format it, I am not using any plugin or jQuery to format it. I suggested you plugin in case you have various formats to format the date.

Comment: Here the detail. I have a div than has to be loaded when the page opens. So on .load() i want an ajax request sending the date of the beginning of the week to a php file which retrieves the records for the 30 days after that day. So I need to send that date to my php file so that it can retrieve the records based on that date. So the date format has to be maintained while formating the variable. Is it clear to you?

Comment: Shankar. Consider this post close. I tried the plugin you suggested me eventhough I try to use external plugins as little as possible. It seems to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , but check if this might help

```
var now = new Date();
var curr_date = now.getDate();
var curr_month = now.getMonth();
var curr_year = now.getFullYear();
alert((curr_month+1)+'-'+curr_date+'-'+curr_year);
```

Comment: Hello Bugger. The behavior of your code is not the one I excpect. In addition what I am trying to do is to format the date while keeping it as a date. Thanks anyway.